# max function does not when having case when clause

Tags: sql, hive

i have two tables.
one is as below

table a

```
ID, count
1,  123
2,  123
3,  123
```

table b

```
ID, count
```

table b is empty

when using

```
 
SELECT CASE
    WHEN isnotnull(max(b.count)) THEN max(a.count) + max(b.count)
    ELSE max(a.count)
FROM a, b
```

the only result is always NULL
i am very confused. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `JOIN`, a simple `SUM` of two sub-queries will give you your desired result. Since you only add `MAX(b.count)` when it is non-`NULL`, we can just add it all the time but `COALESCE` it to 0 when it is `NULL`.

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(count) FROM b), 0) + (SELECT MAX(count) FROM a)
```

Another way to make this work is to `UNION` the `count` values from each table:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(bcount), 0) + MAX(acount)
FROM (SELECT count AS acount, NULL AS bcount FROM a
      UNION
      SELECT NULL AS acount, count AS bcount FROM b) u
```

Note that if you use a `JOIN` it **must** be a `FULL JOIN`. If you use a `LEFT JOIN` you risk not seeing all the values from table b. For example, consider the case where table b has one entry: `ID=4, count=456`. A `LEFT JOIN` on `ID` will not include this value in the result table (since table a only has ID values of 1,2 and 3) so you will get the wrong result:

```
CREATE TABLE a (ID INT, count INT);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 123), (2, 123), (3, 123);
CREATE TABLE b (ID INT, count INT);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (4, 456);
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(b.count), 0) + MAX(a.count)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Output

```
123 (should be 579)
```

To use a `FULL JOIN` you would write

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(b.count), 0) + MAX(a.count)
FROM a
FULL JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: you explained very clearly and really helped me to understand what caused my issue.thank you very much.

Comment: i tried, it seems hive does not support SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(count) FROM b), 0) + (SELECT MAX(count) FROM a) . it always report me that 'cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'MAX' '(' in expression specification'

Comment: @vitoyan My apologies, I did not realise hive was so limited. This query will work in all the flavours of SQL I am familiar with. I'm glad you had another answer that will work.

Comment: @vitoyan please see my updated answer. It has a couple of queries that will work in hive. Also it explains why you cannot use a `LEFT JOIN` for this query and guarantee that you will get the correct result.

Comment: sorry for replying so late. thank you for your so detail explanation. yes, I can not use 'LEFT JOIN'. I tried with your suggestion and got an expected result. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since, table`b` is empty, `max(b.count)` will return `NULL`. And any operation done with NULL, results in `NULL`.

So, `max(a.count) + max(b.count)`  is NULL.`(this is 123 + NULL which will be NULL always)`. Hence, your query is returning NULL.

Just use a `coalesce` to assign a default value whenever NULL comes.

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use `coalesce()` function and explicit join, avoid coma separated table name type old join method

```
  select coalesce(max(a.count)+max(b.count),max(a.count))
  from a left join b on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join

```
SELECT coalesce(max(a.count) + max(b.count),max(a.count))
   FROM a left join b a.id=b.id
```